# SmarterCSV and resque results in undefined method close

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, resque, smartercsv

I am trying to use [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) and [SmarterCSV](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) but keep seeing the same error:

> `undefined method 'close' for nil:NilClass`

in my resque logs.  I'm not sure why it's happening.  I've done some digging and people who have seen this found it has to do with a file location being wrong, but I'm simply passing the file as a param, it's not saved anywhere.

**My Form:**

```
<%= form_tag check_upload_file_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= select_tag 'location', options_from_collection_for_select(Location.real, 'id', 'name'), include_blank: true %>
    <br>
    <%= submit_tag "Preview", class: "btn btn-awaken btn-sm approve-me", name: 'preview' %>
<% end %>
```

**My Controller:**

```
def check_upload_file
    Resque.enqueue(AddClientsFromScale, params[:file], params[:location])
    redirect_to bulk_uploads_path
end
```

**My worker:**

```
class AddClientsFromScale
    @queue = :validate_file

    puts "adding clients from scale..."

    def self.perform(file, location_id)
        p file, location_id
        WeighIn.check_file(file, location_id)
    end
end
```

**My model:**

```
class WeighIn < ActiveRecord::Base
    @hash_for_new_clients = {
        ' ID'                           => 'scale_id',
        'Full Name'                     => 'name',
    }

    def self.check_file(file, location_id)
        options = {:key_mapping => @hash_for_new_clients, :strings_as_keys => true, :keep_original_headers => true, :remove_unmapped_keys => true}

        # prints the file and contents properly
        p "file: ", file["tempfile"] 

        SmarterCSV.process(file, options) do |row|
            p row
        end
    end
end
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `file` variable is a hash containing more data than just the file itself. The clue is where you print it using `file["tempfile"]`. That's what you need to plug into SmarterCSV, because that is what references the actual file you're trying to process.

```
SmarterCSV.process(file["tempfile"], options) do |row|
```

In my case I had an additional file encoding issue where I received this error from SmarterCSV:

> WARNING: you are trying to process UTF-8 input, but did not open the input with "b:utf-8" option. See README file "NOTES about File Encodings".

This was what did it for me in the end:

```
f = File.open(file["tempfile"], "r:bom|utf-8")
SmarterCSV.process(f, options) do |row|
    ...
```